# Trying to add rows to a table dynamically is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to provide a way for the users of my web application to be able to dynamically add more first / last name fields to a form that needs to be filled out as a part of a create widget type page.

**Problem**

The code works in that it creates a new set of first/last name fields, but it appends it in the wrong spot... it puts it at the top of the form instead of under the first set of first/last name fields.

**Code:**

This is what the HTML table looks like:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">     
 <tr><td colspan="3"><input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Location" name="location" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="3"><input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Department" name="department" /></td></tr>
 <div id='listofnames'>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" /></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Last Name" name="Lname" /></td>
             <td><button id='addname' type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></td>                                
        </tr>
 </div>
 <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Assign" /></td></tr>
 </table>
```

The  you see is my attempt to isolate the area where I want to add new rows.

When the user clicks on the "addname" button, I have the following code execute:

```
$( "#addname" ).click(function() {

  htmlstring ="<tr>";
  htmlstring += "<td><input class='form-control' type='input' placeholder='First Name' name='fname' /></td>";
  htmlstring += "<td><input class='form-control' type='input' placeholder='Last Name' name='lname' /></td>";
  htmlstring += "</tr>";
  $( "#listofnames" ).append(htmlstring);

});
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

Using the `.before()` method I changed this:

```
$( "#listofnames" ).append(htmlstring);
```

to this:

```
$( "#assign" ).before(htmlstring);
```

where "assign" is now the id of the button that triggers this all. 
Got the idea from the answer that suggested `.after()`

Comment: `div` is not a table and you should not have `tr` elements inside it... you should double check your structure.

Comment: a minimal table should look like: <table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></table> and you should add tr inside the tbody.

Comment: i'm only showing the partial table... I dont' show the opening <table> tag but it's there. I will add it in now.

Comment: Since you said that there was a table tag there.. Then it would be safe to say that you're targetting the wrong element. Use $("#listofnames table").append(htmlstring)

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question; instead, add the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking something like this:

```js
$("#addname").click(function() {

  htmlstring = "<tr>";
  htmlstring += "<td><input class='form-control' type='input' placeholder='First Name' name='fname' /></td>";
  htmlstring += "<td><input class='form-control' type='input' placeholder='Last Name' name='lname' /></td>";
  htmlstring += "</tr>";
  $("#listofnames").after(htmlstring);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Location" name="location" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Department" name="department" />
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr id='listofnames'>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" type="input" placeholder="Last Name" name="Lname" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button id='addname' type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle">append</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Assign" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: cool.  so far, this is the closest to actually working.  the only problem is when you click the add button more than once.  The new row is added always in the same spot vs. at the bottom of the list.  I'm not sure if this is a show stopper ... will have to think about it.

Comment: what if i do the reverse?  if there's a .before() method I can call, I will add before the button.

Comment: before OR after you can use as per your requirement :)

Comment: marking this as the answer since the after() triggered the before() idea!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

$(this).before(htmlstring);

Answer (score -1):

try changing

```
$( "#listofnames" ).append(htmlstring);
```

for

```
$( "#listofnames" ).html(htmlstring);
```

Comment: i believe html() just replaces the entire html that's already there.  so this will not work